# Getting an average from JSON in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application for which I'm trying to show the average salary for each employee that I am getting from my data.json file. I am able to output all the salaries but unsure of how to get the average of all the salaries on the screen. I'm pretty new to React so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [data,setData]=useState([]);
  const getData=()=>{
    fetch('data.json'
    ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }
    )
      .then(function(response){
        // console.log(response)
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        setData(myJson)
      });
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[])

  const avg = () => {
    return console.log(data);
  }

  return (

    <div className="App">
     {data && data.length>0 && data.map((item)=><p>{item.Salary}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `useMemo` hook for this. It could look sth like this:

```
const avg = useMemo(() => {
  if (data.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  
  return data.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.Salary, 0) / data.length;
}, [data])
```

The memo hook receives a dependency array. In this case, it is `[data]`. Whenever a value in the dependency array changes, the `useMemo` hook is recomputed and the value is accessible via the constant.

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried this and at first it said "sum" is not defined. I put sum into the argument after useMemo and now I'm getting back NaN.

Comment: I fixed my answer, please have a look at it again and consider marking it as the correct answer :)

Comment: You can read more about `Array.reduce` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

And more about the `useMemo` hook here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: I'm still receiving NaN for some reason.

Comment: Have you ensured that `item.Salary` is always a valid number?

Comment: I checked and it seems fine. Here is my json file:
```
[
  {
    "name":"Abreu, Jose",
    "Salary":"11666667",
    "Year":"2016"
  },
  {
    "name":"Acevedo, Andury",
    "Salary":"507500",
    "Year":"2016",
    "Level":"MLB"
    },
    {
    "name":"Ackley, Dustin",
    "Salary":"3200000",
    "Year":"2016",
    "Level":"MLB"
    },
    {
    "name":"Adames, Cristhian",
    "Salary":"507500",
    "Year":"2016",
    "Level":"MLB"
    }    
]
```
The number I get back using avg is "2.91666687687508e+25"

Comment: The issue is that the salary values are not integers but strings inside your JSON object. you have to either fix your JSON and remove the quotes around the number or you have to deal with it in the code. If you do it in code, change `sum + item.Salary` to `sum + Number.parseInt(item.Salary, 10)`.
And please consider accepting this answer :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I completely missed that the values were passed as strings. All works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to duplicate all of that code every time you need a bit of JSON in your components. You can begin by writing a generic `useAsync` [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) -

```js
// hooks.js

import { useState, useEffect } from React

const useAsync = (runAsync, deps = []) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  
  useEffect(_ => {
    Promise.resolve(runAsync(...deps))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, deps)

  return { loading, error, result }
}

export { useAsync }
```

You're excited so you start using it right away -

```js
// MyComponent.js

import { useAsync } from "./hooks.js"

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { loading, error, result:items } =
    useAsync(_ => {
      axios.get("path/to/json")
        .then(res => res.json())
    }, ...)

  // ...
}

export default MyComponent
```

But stop there. Write more useful hooks when you need them -

```js
// hooks.js (continued)

const useAysnc = //...

const fetchJson = (url) =>
  fetch(url, {
    headers : { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(r => r.json())

const useJson = (url) =>
  useAsync(fetchJson, [url])

export { useAsync, useJson }
```

Now it's dead-simple to fetch JSON in any component. Reusable generic functions reduces the chance you introduce bugs to your own code. And you get all the possible states: `loading`, `error`, or `result` -

```js
// MyComponent.js

import { useJson } from "./hooks.js"

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { loading, error, result:items } =
    useJson("path/to/json")

  if (loading)
    return <p>Loading...</p>

  if (error)
    return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>

  return <div><Items items={items} /></div> // example use of `items`
}

export default MyComponent
```

Caclculating `average` is a matter of using another generic function, `sum` -

```js
// stats.js

const average = a =>
  sum(a) / a.length

const sum = a =>
  a.reduce((s, v) => s + v, 0)

export { average, sum }
```

Noticing a pattern? Isolate behaviour and write reusable functions. Import them where needed. Here's how we use `average` in your component -

```js
// MyComponent.js

import { average } from "./stats.js"
import { useJson } from "./hooks.js"

const MyComponent = () => {
  // useJson...

  <div>Average: {average(items.map(v => v.Salary))}</div>
}

export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the sum of all salaries and then find the average of it.

```js
let salaries=[2,3,8,1];
let sum=0;
for(let i=0;i<salaries.length;i++){
  sum=sum+salaries[i];
}
average=sum/salaries.length;
console.log(average);
```

Comment: This will yield `Infinity` if the length is zero. Furthermore, I think this does not answer the question, as the question was rather about how to do it in react and hence as a result of a change of the `data` state.